# How do I make Ajax update every 10 seconds in jquery?

Tags: ajax, jquery

How do I make Ajax update every 10 seconds in jquery?

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: options.feedUrl,
    dataType: "xml",
    async:options.sync,
    success: function(xml) {
        }
```

For example I am testing the jquery above to get a RSS feed. So how do you make it update the RSS every 10 seconds so the user can see a new item in the feed?

Answer (score 7):

Creating an interval

```
var ResInterval = window.setInterval('myAjaxCall()', 60000); // 60 seconds

var myAjaxCall = function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: options.feedUrl,
    dataType: "xml",
    async:options.sync,
    success: function(xml) {
        // todo
    }
};
```

To stop

```
window.clearInterval(ResInterval);
```

Comment: doesn't it have to be var resInterval then because of .clearInterval(resInterval); ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid the synchronous ajax call. It'll make anything else on the page like animations freeze. Of course with asynchronous calls you'll need to make sure they don't start overlapping. In your setInterval you could just put a lock:

```
var doingAjax = false;

setInterval(function() {
  if (!doingAjax) {
    doingAjax = true;
    jQuery.ajax({
      ...,
      success: function() {
        doingAjax = false;
        ...
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: thank it work but not the way i want it to it jut no like twitter dose it

Answer (score 0):

wrap it in a function and use setInterval()