# Submit form in a loop with time interval with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Ok i have this portion of code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxsbmt.js"></script>
<?php
for ($i=0; $i <=20; $i++) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        $valor = "";
        $desde= "";
        $inicio = "0";
         }
         else {
        $valor = ($i*50)+1;
        $desde = "_Desde_";
              }
    $analisar = $_POST['string']."".$desde."".$valor;
             // echo $valor;
    ?>
<div style="float:left;">
<form id="formproduto<?php echo $valor; ?>" name="form<?php echo $valor; ?>" action="#produto" method="post" onsubmit="xmlhttpPost('analisar.php', 'formproduto<?php echo $valor; ?>', 'produto', '&lt;img src=\'ajax-loader.gif\'&gt;'); return false;"><input type="hidden" value="<?=$analisar?>" name="analisar" />
<input type="submit" value="<?php if ($i == 0) { echo $inicio; } else { echo $valor; } ?>" />
</form>
</div>
<?php } ?>

<div id="produto"></div>
```

What i need is to submit the loop (using my already existant ajaxsbmt.js routine (that get the form value and show into the div "produto"

BUT i would like this script runs automatically, like after 5 seconds delay each other for example

So its gona be like this,
When i press submit (or "0" button for example) the javascript (or another thing) submit that form wait for the results and then wait N seconds until the next step of the loop.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You will have to find a way to use `setTimeout` and call the function that sends the form using ajax, and when you receive the feed back you will redo the same process and increment a variable until it reaches n times.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to use `setInterval` function like below :

Creating an interval

```
var ResInterval = window.setInterval('myAjaxCall()', 60000); // 60 seconds

var myAjaxCall = function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: options.feedUrl,
    dataType: "xml",
    async:options.sync,
    success: function(xml) {
        // todo
    }
};
```

To stop

```
window.clearInterval(resInterval);
```

Code taken from the below link:

[How do I make Ajax update every 10 seconds in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928523/how-do-i-make-ajax-update-every-10-seconds-in-jquery)

Comment: `setInterval('myAjaxCall()', 60000)`. You're using eval for no reason here. Use `setInterval(myAjaxCall, 60000)`