# Refresh a certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can anyone give me advice on how to make a div refresh.

I'm making a chess game and I want the div to load every time the other player posts data into the database. My game is almost finished the thing is, when you move a piece, Player 2 wont see the move that Player 1 made, when Player 2 refreshes the browser he/she can now see that the Player 1 has moved a piece.

How can I achieve this automatically?

I'm using jQuery and Ajax.

Comment: assign an ID to that div, like id="row1_col1"

Comment: yes sir so this is my element <div id=board>some codes</div>.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: I would refresh the window every x seconds using an AJAx call to disply the current state of the game.

Comment: You can use setInterval method to fire an AJAX request after every fixed time interval and change the contents of a certain div according to database status.

Comment: [Here the board](http://jsfiddle.net/4KLHs/15/). how can i make this board refresh?
sir @LuigiEdlCarno yes im using ajax to call data, but it cant display the moving css.

Comment: You need black and white board :p

Comment: sir @SarathSprakash the code is to long and probably every one will not understand it.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928523/how-do-i-make-ajax-update-every-10-seconds-in-jquery)

Comment: sir @LuigiEdlCarno i also use setInterval to load the board, but it happens that it append the cell to the board and i got lots of cell in my board.

Comment: sir @LuigiEdlCarno see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4KLHs/16/) this is what happen when i use setInterval

Comment: You should clear the chessboard, before redrawing it.

Comment: yes I think it would be great but how can I?

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = setupRefresh;
var interval = 1000;


    function setupRefresh() {
        setTimeout("refreshPage();", interval); // milliseconds
    }

    function refreshPage() {
        //get game state using ajax and update div
    }
```

this will refresh every second (== 1000ms, change to what you want/need), you need to implement the stuff in refreshPage()

Comment: Why not pass the function reference to `setTimeout()` instead of passing a string and implicitly calling `eval()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,[Auto Load and Refresh Div every 10 Seconds with jQuery.](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/auto-load-refresh-every-10-seconds-with.html)
cant answer more without showing what you already done?

Comment: yes thank you for answering sir @Sobin, [look at some of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/4KLHs/16/). sorry my code is to long that i cant put it in jsFiddle.

Comment: whats happening there?

Comment: the cells append to the board and it loop and loop, so the cell append and append to the board.

Comment: change $('#board').append(str); to $('#board').html(str);

Comment: sir @Sobin it work, but now cant move the piece. noted, I'll think for some logic how to make it work and I think clearinterval will do the trick. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hope something like this might help you... :)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(targetDiv, 1000); 
    }); 

    function targetDiv(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/refresh_your_div_function",
      //Other code u need to perform
     }).done(function() {
       //Your code
     });
    }
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but it happens that when i use setInterval it  adds lot of cell in my board.

Comment: @reyes.Seriously i can't understand why setinterval adds lot of cell in the board..???Could you provide more information on this...

Comment: yes, so what happens is it append the cell in the board. you can see the function drawBoard it has $('#board').append(str); that append the str to the board, so when we put setInterval it append and append and append.